# SSIS - AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

We updated our servers with windows updates and one of my ssis dataflow task errored out.After checking the package I found the connection string is throwing the following acquireconnection error along with TCP: failed to establish a connection.

[image: Error]

Things I have checked:

- Client and Server protocols have been enabled tcp/ip,named pipes.
- Remote Server allows remote connections.
- The account has permissions to the server.I can connect to the server
  using the login credentials.
- The server is online.
- Set 'run64bitRuntime' to False
- Set delay validation to true

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.Someone had `disabled ssl 2.0 and enabled tls 1.2` on the remote host running the SQL Server. I had to do the same on the server that was trying to connect to the remote server.

Note: You can do this manually using regedit and will require a restart of the server.

Create a DWORD key value pair for `DisabledByDefault with value Ox00000000 and Enabled with value 0xffffffff`

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for returning with your answer.